# assembly: limit of uninitialized data section .bss?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, intel

I have the following x86_64 assembly program (Intel syntax):

```
%define BUFSIZE 3000000000

        section .bss

buf:    resb  BUFSIZE
        
section .text

        global _start

_start:
```

When I invoke `nasm -f elf64 bsstest.asm` (with version 2.13.02), I get the following error message: `bsstest.asm:5: panic: assertion data.insoffs == insn_size failed at asm/assemble.c:725`.

If I reduce `BUFSIZE` to `2000000000`, the error disappears. It seems, the uninitialized data segment is restricted to 2 GB. Why is this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

Edit: actually, the limits only seems to relate to a single `resb`, I can have multiple `resb` which add up to more than 2 GB.

Comment: This looks like a bug in NASM.  It is possible that it stores symbol sizes as 32 bit numbers.

Comment: Yes, known issue: [bug #3392721 “Problems with very large resb and times counts”](https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392721).

Comment: @KaiBurghardt already linked my bug report. As hpa replied there, "there are a large number of places in the NASM codebase where a length is represented by a signed int32_t".

Comment: You probably want to avoid such a large .bss if possible, so that you can stick to the more efficient small/PIC [code model](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/03/understanding-the-x64-code-models).  Normally you'd allocate that kind of large object dynamically at runtime (malloc / mmap / etc).  That also lets you fail gracefully or fall back in case there isn't enough memory available, instead of just having your program fail to start at all.

Comment: @NateEldredge: If you have the linker put the BSS at the end of your program (like it does by default I think), you can use a code model where all symbols except the large arrays are reachable with RIP-relative addressing (i.e. `-mcmodel=medium`).  (And 32-bit absolute for non-PIE).  And if you only have one huge array, the *start* of it can be reachable with 32-bit rel/abs, unlike the *medium* code model where all things larger than the large-data threshold are assumed to *start* above 2GB.  So for example you could still do `mov eax, [buf + rdi]` with this.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Yes, in principle, but I wouldn't guess that linkers are smart enough to handle one huge array that way.  I suspect that if static code/data including .bss exceeds 2 GB, it will just barf and tell you to rebuild with a larger code model, instead of trying to rearrange things.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh, yeah, you'd have to make sure your huge array was the last thing in the BSS.  But this is assembly language so you can do that.  But I don't think the linker itself knows what a "code model" is; it just knows whether relocations can reach or not, on a per-relocation basis.  `gcc -mcmodel=medium` is a code-gen option to use `movabs` imm64 to put addresses into registers for certain symbols, and an agreement about which symbols it will do that for, so those symbols *can* be outside the low 2G range if necessary.  (That's my understanding, anyway.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: The `ld` man page's only mention of "model" is `-Tldata-segment=org` which says where to start the large-data segment *if there is one*.  So yeah, other aspects of the "code model" are how GCC chooses to use the available building blocks and layout possibilities.  i.e. stuff you do manually in asm.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the helpful comments. First remark: This is really assembly language. It's a task for my students and I wanted to avoid the cumbersome memory allocation in assembly. Second remark: Using `buf` as immediate in a memory access leads to problems with multiple buffers (as the immediate is only signed 4 byte), so one has to load `buf` into a 64-bit register and use that. A question: the Intel SDM (vol. 2, June 21) doesn't contain anything about a `MOVABS` instruction. Can someone please point me to a description?